# Issue with Oracle REST POST request returning sys_refcursor

Tags: oracle, rest, post, sys-refcursor, oracle-ords

We are currently prototyping a REST API using the Oracle APEX cloud free tier.  I’m having an issue with returning a sys_refcursor in an Oracle REST POST request.  Here’s the particulars (I'm new at asking questions here so I hope the formatting is readable:

**TABLE**

```
 CREATE TABLE "WF_PROTOTYPE"."INGREDIENT_TYPES"     
(   "ID" NUMBER(10,0)  NOT NULL ENABLE,     
    "ACCOUNT_ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "NAME"  VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CREATED_AT" TIMESTAMP (6),     "UPDATED_AT" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "DELETED_AT" TIMESTAMP (6),     "CREATED_BY" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "UPDATED_BY" NUMBER(10,0),      "DELETED_BY" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP",     
 CONSTRAINT "INGR_TYPE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID"))
```

**TRIGGER**

```
create or replace TRIGGER ingredient_types_id_TRIG BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON ingredient_types
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
v_newVal NUMBER(12) := 0;
v_incval NUMBER(12) := 0;
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING AND :new.id IS NULL THEN
    SELECT  ingredient_types_id_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO v_newVal FROM DUAL;
    -- If this is the first time this table have been inserted into (sequence == 1)
    IF v_newVal = 1 THEN 
      --get the max indentity value from the table
      SELECT NVL(max(id),0) INTO v_newVal FROM ingredient_types;
      v_newVal := v_newVal + 1;
      --set the sequence to that value
      LOOP
           EXIT WHEN v_incval>=v_newVal;
           SELECT ingredient_types_id_SEQ.nextval INTO v_incval FROM dual;
      END LOOP;
    END IF;
   -- assign the value from the sequence to emulate the identity column
   :new.id := v_newVal;
  END IF;
END;
```

**STORED PROCEDURE**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ingredient_type_POST (
   p_account_id     IN  ingredient_types.account_id%TYPE,
   p_name           IN  ingredient_types.name%TYPE,
   p_description    in  ingredient_types.description%type,
   p_created_by     IN  ingredient_types.created_by%type,
   p_out_rec        OUT sys_refcursor
)
AS
    new_id ingredient_types.id%type;
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO ingredient_types (account_id, name, DESCRIPTION, created_at, created_by)
   VALUES (p_account_id, p_name, p_description, systimestamp, nvl(p_created_by,2))
   RETURN id INTO new_id;

   OPEN p_out_rec FOR
    SELECT id, account_id, name, description
    FROM   ingredient_types
    WHERE  ID = new_id;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN HTP.print(SQLERRM);
END ingredient_type_POST;
```

**ORDS DEFINITION**

```
ORDS.DEFINE_HANDLER(
      p_module_name    => 'wf_api.rest',
      p_pattern        => 'accounts/:acct_id/ingredient_types',
      p_method         => 'POST',
      p_source_type    => 'plsql/block',
      p_items_per_page =>  0,
      p_mimes_allowed  => '',
      p_comments       => 'CREATE an Ingredient Type',
      p_source         => 
'begin
    INGREDIENT_TYPE_POST(
                p_account_id    => :acct_id, 
                p_name          => :name, 
                p_description   => :description,
                p_created_by    => :APP_USER, 
                p_rec           => :new_rec);
end;'
      );
  ORDS.DEFINE_PARAMETER(
      p_module_name        => 'wf_api.rest',
      p_pattern            => 'accounts/:acct_id/ingredient_types',
      p_method             => 'POST',
      p_name               => 'rec',
      p_bind_variable_name => 'new_rec',
      p_source_type        => 'RESPONSE',
      p_param_type         => 'RESULTSET',
      p_access_method      => 'OUT',
      p_comments           => NULL);
```

When I run the SP from the SQL Developer worksheet EDITOR, filling in the input variables I get a successful result (New record created) and it returns the anticipated resultset in the p_out_rec parameter.  However, when I run it in the HANDLER editor, filling out the appropriate variables, I get the following error message:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
begin
    INGREDIENT_TYPE_POST(
                p_account_id    => :acct_id, 
                p_name          => :name, 
                p_description   => :description,
                p_created_by    => :APP_USER, 
                p_rec           => :new_rec);
end;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INGREDIENT_TYPE_POST'
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

I’ve tried to mimic ThatJeffSmith’s tutorial https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/03/parameters-and-binds-for-your-restful-services-resultsets/ as closely as possible, and I’m not seeing where my fault lies… any insights greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Your procedure was defined with `p_out_rec` but you're calling it with `p_rec`.

Comment: you're not supplying a value for the ID column, and it's NOT NULL, so that won't work...unless you have a sequence/trigger or IDENTITY column defined that you're not showing in your code sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a couple of issues with your code.

1. you're not supplying a value for the table's ID column
2. your refcursor is being populated with a query that will mostly never
   work, you're checking the ID against the ACCOUNT_ID value
3. you're referring to p_out_rec as p_rec -- thanks @andrew!

Here's how it could work

[image]

```
-- Generated by ORDS REST Data Services 20.4.1.r0131644
-- Schema: HR  Date: Wed Mar 17 05:24:17 2021 
--

BEGIN
  ORDS.ENABLE_SCHEMA(
      p_enabled             => TRUE,
      p_schema              => 'HR',
      p_url_mapping_type    => 'BASE_PATH',
      p_url_mapping_pattern => 'hr',
      p_auto_rest_auth      => FALSE);
    
  ORDS.DEFINE_MODULE(
      p_module_name    => 'wf_api.rest',
      p_base_path      => '/wf_api/',
      p_items_per_page => 25,
      p_status         => 'PUBLISHED',
      p_comments       => 'stackoverflow question');

  ORDS.DEFINE_TEMPLATE(
      p_module_name    => 'wf_api.rest',
      p_pattern        => 'accounts/:acct_id/ingredient_types',
      p_priority       => 0,
      p_etag_type      => 'HASH',
      p_etag_query     => NULL,
      p_comments       => NULL);

  ORDS.DEFINE_HANDLER(
      p_module_name    => 'wf_api.rest',
      p_pattern        => 'accounts/:acct_id/ingredient_types',
      p_method         => 'POST',
      p_source_type    => 'plsql/block',
      p_mimes_allowed  => '',
      p_comments       => NULL,
      p_source         => 
'begin
 INGREDIENT_TYPE_POST(
    P_ID             => :id,
    P_ACCOUNT_ID     => :acct_id,
    P_NAME           => :name,
    P_DESCRIPTION    => :description,
    P_CREATED_BY     => :APP_USER,
    P_OUT_REC        => :new_rec
  );
END;');

  ORDS.DEFINE_PARAMETER(
      p_module_name        => 'wf_api.rest',
      p_pattern            => 'accounts/:acct_id/ingredient_types',
      p_method             => 'POST',
      p_name               => 'rec',
      p_bind_variable_name => 'new_rec',
      p_source_type        => 'RESPONSE',
      p_param_type         => 'RESULTSET',
      p_access_method      => 'OUT',
      p_comments           => NULL);

    
        
COMMIT;

END;
```

And the PL/SQL proc...

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ingredient_type_POST (
   p_id             IN  ingredient_types.id%TYPE,
   p_account_id     IN  ingredient_types.account_id%TYPE,
   p_name           IN  ingredient_types.name%TYPE,
   p_description    in  ingredient_types.description%type,
   p_created_by     IN  ingredient_types.created_by%type,
   p_out_rec        OUT sys_refcursor
)
AS
    new_id ingredient_types.id%type;
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO ingredient_types (id, account_id, name, DESCRIPTION, created_at, created_by)
   VALUES (p_id, p_account_id, p_name, p_description, systimestamp, nvl(p_created_by,2))
   RETURN id INTO new_id;

   OPEN p_out_rec FOR
    SELECT id, account_id, name, description
    FROM   ingredient_types
    WHERE  account_ID = p_account_id;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN HTP.print(SQLERRM);
END ingredient_type_POST;
```

And the request -

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:8080/ords/hr/wf_api/accounts/42/ingredient_types \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
    "id".         : 55,
    "name"        : "heyYou",
    "description" : "some words",
    "APP_USER"    : 44
}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your responses!  The ID column is being populated with a sequence so I do not want to populate that.  .  The account_id is different.  An ACCOUNT can have many associated INGREDIENT_TYPES, so when I return a record, I do not want to return all the INGREDIENT_TYPES for an Account, I just want to return the JUST INSERTED row's info.  Good catch on my p_rec / p_out_rec issue.  Let me take a closer look.  It seems you got it returning the resultset.

Comment: next time, include your REAL scenario, then i can get closer to helping you. otherwise, we're left to guessing.

Comment: Sorry.  I guess I did not make it clear enough.  I put this in the Heading above my table DDL ==>  TABLE (it has a trigger to populate ID which I did not include)

As I tried to explain, the Stored Procedure seems to work as expected when I test it in SQL Dvlpr.  It doesn't work when it is called by the Handler, leading me to believe I've got the Parameters messed up somehow... But I'm new at this.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No worries! See what I did, adjust your code, have another go, and report back!

Comment: I tried adding the p_id and bypassing the trigger and populating ID explicitly as you did.  Once again, the SP works using the green arrow, but I get the same error when calling it from the ORDS Handler (using the green arrow.)  I'm trying to get as close to your example as possible.  It may be Monday before I take this back up.

Comment: Just got back to this.  I switched the SP and the Handler up to just return the newly generated ID field, and it worked.  So it does not return the refcursor.  I think I will go with this for the time being, although I'd much rather return all the values that were entered, but I'm gonna cut my losses for now.  Thanks for your insights.  I love your blogs!